# All templates get applied to first document despite multiple compositeTemplate objects

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Here is the case I am trying to solve with the compositeTemplates approach to creating envelopes. I want to provide my own document to DocuSign and define some of my own custom tabs, while also using DocuSign's template feature.

So far, when I only send one document, it works perfectly and I get what I want: a DocuSign that has both the template I applied and the custom tabs I added.

However, when I start sending multiple compositeTemplates (I am only sending one document per compositeTemplate object), it seems that all my server templates only get applied to the first document (the document of the first compositeTemplate object in the array), and not the document in that server template's respective compositeTemplate object. My inline templates are still getting correctly applied to their respective document.

Am I using composite templates incorrectly? I have copied the code used to create the compositeTemplates below:

```
      const compositeTemplates = _.map(rawDocuments, rawDoc => {
        const serverTemplates = []

        if (rawDoc.templateId) {
          const serverTemplate = docusign.ServerTemplate.constructFromObject({
            sequence: '2',
            templateId: rawDoc.templateId
          })

          serverTemplates.push(serverTemplate)
        }

        return docusign.CompositeTemplate.constructFromObject({
          document: docusign.Document.constructFromObject(rawDoc),
          serverTemplates,
          inlineTemplates: [docusign.InlineTemplate.constructFromObject({
            sequence: '1',
            recipients: constructSigners(rawSigners, rawDoc)
          })]
        })
      })
```

Additional Information:

- I am using two separate templates, and each template is only responsible for one document.
- I am also replacing the server template document with the exact same document (slightly different information, but has same structure and number of pages)
- The request JSON looks like this:

```
[
 {
   document: {
     documentBase64: '...'
     documentId: '1',
     fileExtension: 'pdf',
     name: 'test',
   },
   serverTemplates: [{
     sequence: '2',
     templateId: 'fee45537-2a77-46c0-ad68-d4ffa22ec763'
   }],
   inlineTemplates: [{
     sequence: '1',
     recipients: '...'
   }]
 },
 {
   document: {
     documentBase64: '...'
     documentId: '2',
     fileExtension: 'pdf',
     name: 'New',
   },
   serverTemplates: [{
     sequence: '2',
     templateId: 'b66272b2-038a-4071-aa77-08a5e635e470'
   }],
   inlineTemplates: [{
     sequence: '1',
     recipients: '...'
   }]
 }
]
```

Comment: you have docuentId "1" for the first and "2" for the second. Are the templates set this way? is it possible you just need "1" for both?

Comment: Changing the documentId to "1" for both solved the issue of the template being only applied to the first document! Can you explain why? However, it messed up the custom tabs that I am sending over because those refer to specific documentIds.

Comment: See Drew's answer. But you can fix the tabs if you need to, but your scenario may be more complex, not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

When using composite templates, the DocumentId in each Composite Template needs to match the DocumentId in the Server Template in order to replace it.

Note that there's no conflict between duplicate IDs from one composite template to another - recipient IDs and document IDs get renumbered when the API call is processed.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. I don't see anywhere on the DocuSign editor interface that specifies for a DocumentId. Also, the documents on the server template are getting replaced as far as I know, but the server templates are getting applied incorrectly

Comment: to check the document IDs on a template, try a GET call to `/templates/[template_id]/documents`: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/TemplateDocuments/list

Answer (score 1):

### Determining the document IDs for a template's documents

The template's first document usually has ID 1. To see the document's ID:

1. Open the template for editing
2. Click View for the document of interest
3. On the document's modal display: open the browser's menu and choose "Open image in new tab"
4. Inspect the new URL. The number after /documents/ is the document ID. Eg URL .../documents/456/pages/... has document ID 456